# WCAG luminance contrasts - current practice, what is it?

Tags: color, css, accessibility

I tried to ask this question [in another group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23201677/wcag-luminance-contrasts-current-practice-what-is-it), but got a hint this group might be more appropriate.

I just wrote a little tool to check [luminance contrast (WCAG)](http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/visual-audio-contrast-contrast.html) on a web page. Testing this I was surprised to see that a lot of sites (for example Facebook) uses contrast as low as 2.7 where the recommended contrast is 4.5 (WCAG2 AA).

There are many sites doing that (for example this one ;-) ). It seems like there is some practical consensus. It looks difficult for a designer to avoid using lower contrast on some elements.

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415785/wcag-vs-real-users-opinions) took up a somewhat similar problem. Is there any documentation about this practice with contrast of using low luminance contrast? Some research or some recommendation at W3C that I can not find?

I hope my little tool does not get this wrong. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

> lot of sites (for example Facebook) uses contrast as low as 2.7 where
>   the recommended contrast is 4.5 (WCAG2 AA).

Interesting question.

May I ask you where did you find the 2.7:1 ratio of Facebook's UI?

4.5:1 is the recommended contrast ["between text (and images of text) and background behind the text"](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/G18.html), so I've checked this sample Facebook post:

[image]

The result is:

- Background color is `#fff`;
- Foreground color is `#141823`;
- The contrast ratio is **17.73:1** (Level AAA).

In the sidebar:

[image]

- Background color is `#E9EAED`;
- Foreground color is `#333`;
- Contrast ratio is **10.50:1** (Level AAA).

I've found similar ratios almost everywhere on Facebook UI, so I'd like to know more about where and how you measured the contrast.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Eleonora. I am using a tool I made myself. It is a bookmarklet, [YAVB-C](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/848981/it/yavb/yavbc-test.html) which is not quite ready. However I think you can test a bit with it. For example the text "GROUPS" in the left column on Facebook seems to have low contrast (2.7). Maybe I have made some mistake? I would be glad if you tested and compared with the tools you are using.